# GSQL Insert INTO for edge with TO as multiple vertex types

Tags: tigergraph, gsql

How do you add a hint to your Tigergraph GSQL for insert edge query where the TO vertex are several different possible types each having UUID?

For example, when I tried `INSERT INTO has_edge VALUES (child,parent)`, the error occurs because TO vertex options contains multiple vertex types: "hint must be provided for string type expression"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the TO vertex has multiple possible types, you need to disambiguate it with a vertex hint like this:

```
INSERT INTO has_edge VALUES("1", "1" vertexHint)
```

where vertexHint is the name of the vertex that you want the edge to point to.